# Error rendering js partials (links) in Rails for 2FA

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Im building a rails 6 App, and making an attempt to add 2 Factor Auth following Chris Olivers tutorial [GoRails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1Vs1cMSqPM) This is behind a paywall for the full version.

So essentiall whats happening is when I try to render the links on my Profile page I get this `Enable<\/a>\n` as the displayed link and the url that displays on page click is `http://localhost:3000/%22/two_factor/%221`, when I should get a styled button. that reads either "Enable" or "Disable", I have a sneeking suspicion it has to do with use of quotes in my partials (shown below)

Ive spent a few hours trying to chase this, but to no avail. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Screenshot of issue:**

[image: Shows actual render of the button plus Chrome dev tools inspector of the link]

**My Controller: 'app/controllers/two_factors_controller'**

```
class TwoFactorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    current_user.update(
      otp_secret: User.generate_otp_secret,
      otp_required_for_login: true
    )
    @codes = current_user.generate_otp_backup_codes!
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.update(
      otp_required_for_login: false
    )
  end
```

**My create.js.erb: 'app/views/two_factors/create.js.erb**

```
$("#two_factor").html("<%=j render partial: "users/registrations/two_factor" %>");
```

**my destroy.js.erb: 'app/views/two_factors/destroy.js.erb'**

```
$("#two_factor").html("<%=j render partial: "users/registrations/two_factor" %>");
```

**and finally my view partial: 'app/assets/views/users/registrations/_two_factors.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.otp_required_for_login? %>
  <%= link_to "Disable", two_factor_path, method: :delete, remote: :true, class: "btn-alert"%>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Enable", two_factor_path, method: :post, remote: :true, class: "btn-success"%>
<% end %>
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So the final issue was a small one.

I was attempting to render my partial like so `<%= j render partial '.../two_factors  %>` when it needed to be `<%= render partial '.../two_factors  %>` stupid typo that wasted alot fo day.. but a valuable lesson learned!